# Why doesn't FB.login delete the logout cookie?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication, session-management

I have a problem with Facebook authentication logic:

1. On home page load, I call `getLoginStatus()` and if I get `"connected"`, I redirect the user to his account page. If not, the user can click the login button that calls `FB.login()`.
2. If the user is logged in and then navigates back to home page (full page load), `getLoginStatus()` there returns `"connected"` as expected and user gets bounced back to account page.
3. However, when the logged in user calls `FB.logout()` and repeats steps 1-2, the 2nd step will always yield `"unknown"` login status. So, `FB.logout()` basically breaks my bouncing logic.

I checked the mechanics of login/logout calls and it appears `FB.logout()` creates a `fblo_<appId>` cookie with 1 year expiration that blocks `getLoginStatus()` from returning the proper status. This seems to be the actual mechanism for keeping people logged out, which I can understand. What I can't understand, though, is: why this cookie is not deleted on a successful `FB.login()` call?

Comment: Have you checked what paths those cookies are set for?

Comment: There is only one logout cookie `fblo_<appId>` that is set on my whole domain with `/` path. So it's pretty sticky, considering it's not being cleared for a year.

Comment: is there a bug / discussion for this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by programatically deleting the cookie `fblo_<appid>` in callback functions of both FB.login() and FB.logout()

Comment: You for sure DON'T want to do it in logout(). Try this: log into facebook.com like a normal user and authenticate your app on your website. Then in a browser you've never used before log into facebook.com and open your app. You will be automatically logged in because you have already connected. At this point log out and the cookie will get set only on that browser. If you were to delete it you would be automatically logged back in again.

Answer (score -1):

I was experiencing this a few days ago but I'm not seeing the issue any more.

In either case make sure you consider these different scenarios when testing:

> A person logs into Facebook, then logs into your app. Upon logging out from your app, the person is still logged into Facebook.
>
> A person logs into your app and into Facebook as part of your app's login flow. Upon logging out from your app, the user is also logged out of Facebook.
>
> A person logs into another app and into Facebook as part of the other app's login flow, then logs into your app. Upon logging out from either app, the user is logged out of Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

---

Debugging tip:

In the Application tab in Chrome you can select Cookies in the left panel and then type `fblo` into the search box to filter by that name. When I call `FB.login` and successfully authenticate I see that the `fblo` cookie disappears - so I believe this issue fixed.

[image]

Comment: And make use of the 'test user' feature to create test accounts for testing : `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{YOUR-APP-ID}/roles/test-users/`